# Debug a framework while developing

Tags: swift, cocoapods, ios-frameworks, swift-framework

I am creating a statistical calculator app. It has various functions. 
I am creating the functions in a cocoapod framework.
How can we test or debug a library framework while we develop it? That means every time without copying it to the demo/test project.

Answer (score 0):

In your framework project, in Xcode add a target for testing. **Press File > New > Target... > iOS Unit Testing Bundle**.

[image: iOS Unit Testing Bundle]

This will create a test target for you. You can run this target at any time. Also, a swift file with a subclass of `XCTestCase`. This class has all functions necessary for testing, such as `setUp()`, `testExample()` or `testPerformanceExample()`. You can read how to use this in the [XCTest framework reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest).